# Сравнение (==) двух неотсортированных массивов

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка, сравнение

Нужна ваша консультация)

Есть ли алгоритм позволяющий сравнить (равно или нет) содержимое двух неотсортированных массивов?

Т.е. `[3, 2, 1] == [1, 2, 3]`, но можно ли получить в таком случае `True`, не сортируя эти массивы заранее?

Comment: Интересует алгоритм для Питона, но в целом можно и "на словах"

Comment: Можно посчитать XOR хешей элементов, но решение будет с некоторой вероятностью ложно-положительного срабатывания. Для снижения вероятности,  можно считать несколько разных хэшей.

Comment: есть алгоритм - 1 шаг: сортировать. 2 шаг: сравнить. Другой алгоритм: создать словарь с количеством элементов в каждом списке. Если одинаковое - списки одинаковы.

Comment: А элементы все разные или могут повторяться?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать встроенный модуль collections,

```py
import collections 

l1 = [10, 99, 20, 30, 40, 50]
l2 = [10, 20, 30, 99, 50, 40]


if collections.Counter(l1) == collections.Counter(l2):
    print ("Списки l1 и l2 одинаковые")
else:
    print ("Списки l1 и l2 неодинаковые")
```

Answer (score 3):

Сначала нужно ответить на вопрос "а вы с какой целью интересуетесь?" Пример целей:

- затратить наименьшее кол-во усилий
- экономия памяти
- наиболее быстрый алгоритм

И решение в каждом случае будет разное. Например, в третьем случае имеет смысл сначала сравнить длины списков, если они разные - то ответ очевидно `False`. А если длины одинаковые, то можно посчитать (через `Counter` или через словарь) элементы первого списка, а потом идти по второму списку и уменьшать ранее полученные счётчики, если вдруг какой-нибудь из счётчиков упадёт меньше 0, то опять же мы досрочно получаем ответ `False`.

Для экономии памяти тоже можно придумать что-то хитрое, пользуясь тем что в питоне `int` бесконечный и считать как предложили в комментариях что-то типа хитрого хэша, добавляя в него значения при прохождении первого списка и удаляя те же значения при прохождении второго.

Ну а про первый вариант уже написали сравнить два `Counter` между собой.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел библиотеку fuzzywuzzy

Конкретно для этой задачи ответ:

```
    fuzzy.token_sort_ratio([3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3])
```

Вернет: 100%

Comment: Но ведь даже название функции говорит о том, что сравнивается сортированный список. И зачем тогда библиотека? Сортируйте и сравнивайте поэлементно.